# How can I create a pandas DataFrame from a excel file read from HTTP Request?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, file

I have a Azure Function. From Postman, I'm uploading an excel file with name `templateFile`, using form data. Now I want to convert the excel file to a `pandas dataframe`.

This is what data in the excel file looks like:

```
BookId  Title                Author         YearOfPublication
1       One Arranged Murder  Chetan Bhagat  2020
```

This is what I've tried until now, but I got not idea how to move forward.

```py
import pandas as pd
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    templatefile = req.files['templatefile']
    templateStream = templatefile.stream
    text = templateStream.read().decode('utf-8')
```

And also when I try to decode the bytes, it's not happening. I've tried both `utf-8` and `ascii`. Nothing works.
Any suggestions or ideas will be helpful.

Comment: Would you mind sharing an example of the input?

Comment: @Luke Updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df_test = pd.read_excel(req.files['templatefile'].read(), engine='openpyxl')
```